# leaflet route360 using as input point geojson layer?

Tags: javascript, django, routes, leaflet, openlayers

hello I have read this [examples](https://developers.route360.net/guide/leaflet) about leaflet route 360 services.
is very interests but that examples work with static coordinates,my question is how to can use this services using some point GeoJSON layer ?

my GeoJSON layer example:

```
coords = [];
        var points = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'mylayer' %}",{
        onEachFeature:function (feature,layer) {
            coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates.reverse());
            layer.on('click', function (e) {
               var field1=document.getElementById('f1');
               field1.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.name;
            });
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
        }
        });
        points.addTo(map);
```

leaflet route 360 example :

```
  <script>
    // define a pair of coordinates, where the map should be centered
    // and should serve a the source for polygonization
    var latlon = [52.51, 13.37];

    // add the map and set the initial center to berlin
    var map = L.map('map').setView(latlon, 14);
    map.attributionControl.addAttribution("ÖPNV Daten © <a href='https://www.vbb.de/de/index.html' target='_blank'>VBB</a>");

    // initialise the base map
    r360.basemap({ style: 'basic', apikey: '__your-route360-api-key__' }).addTo(map);

    // create the marker and add it to the map
    var marker = L.marker((latlon)).addTo(map);

    // create the layer to add the polygons
    var polygonLayer = r360.leafletPolygonLayer().addTo(map);

    // you need to define some options for the polygon service
    // for more travel options check out the other tutorials
    var travelOptions = r360.travelOptions();
    // please contact us and request your own key if you don't already have one
    travelOptions.setServiceKey('__your-route360-api-key__');
    // set the service url for your area
    travelOptions.setServiceUrl('https://service.route360.net/germany/');
    // we only have one source which is the marker we just added
    travelOptions.addSource(marker);
    // we want to have polygons for 10 to 30 minutes
    travelOptions.setTravelTimes([600, 1200, 1800]);
    // go by foot
    travelOptions.setTravelType('walk');

    // call the r360°- service
    r360.PolygonService.getTravelTimePolygons(travelOptions, function(polygons){
        // add the returned polygons to the polygon layer
        // and zoom the map to fit the polygons perfectly
        polygonLayer.clearAndAddLayers(polygons, true);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What type of geometries are in your GeoJSON data? What does your expected result look like?

Comment: @ghybs is the points,i want to create that services for any point from my GeoJson layer